# Divide dictionaries from API-data into separate columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

Right from the start, I need to point out what will become obvious: I'm more or less a complete beginner, so very concrete, detailed advice and guidance is much appreciated.

I've extracted data from Canvas API, using the following:

`result = requests.get('https://canvas.gu.se/api/v1/courses/xxxxx/assignments/xxxxxx/submissions', params={"include": ["submission_history", "submission_comments"]}, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + canvas_token})`

The data is formatted to json and processed using pandas in Jupyter Notebook. The data specified to be included ends up in one single column, but there should be a way to unpack these dictionaries and its distinctly different content into separate columns. Now it looks like this:

`[{'id': xxxxxx, 'comment': 'Text text text text', 'author_id': 219949, 'author_name': 'Name Name', 'created_at': '2021-11-09T12:13:26Z', 'edited_at': None, 'avatar_path': '/images/users/xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx', 'author': {'id': xxxxxx, 'display_name': 'Name Name', 'avatar_image_url': 'https://canvas.gu.se/images/messages/avatar-50.png', 'html_url': 'https://canvas.gu.se/courses/xxxxx/users/xxxxxx', 'pronouns': None}}, {'id': xxxxxx, 'comment': 'Other text text text text', 'author_id': xxxxxx, 'author_name': 'Name Name', 'created_at': '2021-11-09T12:13:40Z', 'edited_at': None, 'avatar_path': '/images/users/xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx', 'author': {'id': xxxxxx, 'display_name': 'Name Name', 'avatar_image_url': 'https://canvas.gu.se/images/messages/avatar-50.png', 'html_url': 'https://canvas.gu.se/courses/xxxxx/users/xxxxxx', 'pronouns': None}}]`

What I want is to have the comments separately for legibility. I've looked at json_normalize, but can't get it to work.

As a side note: The retrieved data should contain data from över 200 students, but I only get 10. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: you want a list of all comments?

Comment: What you see above is what is found in one cell in the column "submission_comments". I want that data separated into different columns, and the actual comments, here anonymized with "Text text text text", is the information that is I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a list of lists of `dicts`. To get all the comments separately, simply iterate thru the lists and pull out the comments with:

```py
for my_list in df['submission_comments']:
    for d in my_list:
        x = d.get('comment', "")
```

The value of each comment will then be in x and you can do whatever you want with it, perhaps put it in a list or dict of all comments. (Note: `d.get('comment', "")` will return an empty string if `d['comment']` doesn't exist).

Comment: This is what I get when I try this:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-c34107cc5327> in <module>
      1 my_list = df["submission_comments"]
      2 for d in my_list:
----> 3     x = d.get('comment', "")

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Please include a snippet of your code so I can better see what it is you trying to do.

Comment: ´my_list = df["submission_comments"]
for d in my_list:
    x = d.get('comment', "")´

I guess I can't combine pandas with ordinary Python code, but I don't know how to make a list of what is found in the DataFrame to iterate through another way.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the information you have provided...